# Using 'rather' before or after a verb

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Out of the two sentences :

```
I should've  written rather a diary. 

I should've  rather written a diary.
```

Which one's correct if I want to convey the meaning that I wrote something else earlier and now I feel that I should've written a diary ?

Are both sentences grammatically correct?

If so, then is the meaning different in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

Both of these sentences sound odd to my [US-trained] ear. If use of the word *rather* is a requirement, I would suggest either:

> I would rather have written a diary.

Or, keeping with the contractions for an informal feel:

> I’d rather have written a diary.

But a simpler, more direct, more descriptive way to say it is:

> I wish now that I had written a diary instead.

Comment: 'I would rather have written a diary' means 'I would have preferred to write a diary' not 'I wish now that I'd written a diary instead'.

Answer (score 0):

The pragmatic marker (speaker comment) modifies the whole sentence, and doesn't work well near the modal. Better is

> Rather, I should have written a diary.

However, the usage is old fashioned, and

> I should have written a diary instead!

or even just

> I should have written a diary!

sounds less starchy.

Comment: Since the question also asks what the difference in meaning between the two sentences given is, it should be noted that _rather_ in the first version is a submodifier, modifying _a diary_ in a somewhat meaningless and unusual way. Normally, _rather_ submodifies adjectival modifiers (“It's rather a good book / it's a rather good book”), but it can sometimes modify the head noun directly (“He made rather a fuss”). Modifying _diary_ in this way, however, is… odd.

Comment: Could you tell the meaning of "He made rather a fuss" ? What does it imply, exactly?

Comment: Here, _rather_ is, if anything, a minimal intensifier. Dropping it hardly affects the meaning. It makes a slightly softening (hedging) pragmatic  contribution, and can also sound a bit high-faluting.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use *instead* rather than *rather*:

> I should've instead written a diary.

You could also write it as:

> I would rather that I had written a diary.

although this sounds cumbersome to me. It sounds a bit more natural with contraction:

> I'd rather that I'd written a diary.

but this suffers from the fact that *I'd* is used twice, but it's a contraction for different phrases. You could spell one of them out (I'd go with the first one).

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to emphasize? your feeling or your preference.

"now I feel that I should've written a diary" emphasizes your feeling, while "I should've written a diary" emphasizes your preference.

Either way, in context, you have to explain the change. "now I feel that I should've written a diary, rather than [whatever you did before], because [reason], or "I should've written a diary, rather than [whatever], because [reason].

If you have already explained the reason for change, and you just want to summarize, then close with a simple statement of feeling or preference.